# How to retrieve csv/json file from SharePoint document directory with RESTful call

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I tried to create a RESTful call that can be invoked by Angular/JavaScript command to load all data from a csv file or json file and dump them in javascript arrays

I tried

```
https://my.sharepoint.com/site/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items
```

From returned contents it is able to find items but nothing regarding file name. but file id like

```
<id>a03b9f92-abcd-49d8-abcd-d75838917649</id>
```

And if I use

```
https://my.sharepoint.com/site/_api/Web/lists/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/Documents/data.csv')/files
```

it returned 'Cannot find resource for the request GetFileByServerRelativeUrl'

Is there a better way to load data file from library to javascript object?

PS: the reason I have to use document is because SharePoint list has limit of 20k rows. I have a lot rows to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REST API `"/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/test/JS File.js')/$value"`to read data from js/csv files in the Document Library.

**An example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // begin work to call across network
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                      "/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mysite/test/JS File.js')/$value";

        // execute AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {                 
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed to get details");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My test result:

[image]